# Varnish on Nginx not working

Tags: nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I am trying to configure Varnish on Nginx web server.

**Varnish Configuration**

In the file `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {

}

sub vcl_backend_response {
        set beresp.ttl = 10s;
        set beresp.grace = 1h;
}

sub vcl_deliver {

}
```

In the file `/etc/default/varnish`

```
START=yes

NFILES=131072

MEMLOCK=82000


DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

**Nginx Configuration**

In the virtual host file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain`

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    root /var/www/html/domain.com/public_html;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    include hhvm.conf;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

This configuration is not working. When I open `domain.com` on web browser the site does not show anything, but web I open `domain.com:8080` website works.

When I changed port to `listen 80` in virtual host, then `domain.com` works but Varnish is not working on both port `80` and `8080`.

Result After running `curl -I` on both port

[Result After running curl -I on both port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JmBZ.png)

How can I fix this.

Comment: Is the varnish up and running? Or do you get any errors on startup?

Comment: @MichaelHirschler yes, varnish is running. And I did not get any startup errors

Comment: Do you see any logs with `varnishlog` command when running the curl against varnish (:8080) ?